# What's the best way to return the most recent row of data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I have a large stored procedure I'm working on. I'm trying to add query to it that give me the most recent customer order of a particular product.
The trouble is there's nothing that makes the row unique other than the date. I know I need to grab all of the order for the product, including the order date, then ORDER BY OrderDate DESC —the top result is what I need, I'm running into problems isolating the row. 
My query looks something like this (the temp table is part of a long series of temp tables in the query:

```
SELECT t5.*, co.OrderName, co.OrderDate
FROM #TempTable5 t5
JOIN #CustomerOrders co 
ON t5.CustomerGUID = co.CustomerGUID 
WHERE co.OrderSet = 'Product25'
```

This produces the results I need, but obviously with all of the products order. What's the most efficient way to just grab the most recent order? 
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried SELECT TOP 1 t5.*, ....

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 1):

if you have an `id_column` on the table which has an auto increment, you could put on the query :

```
select * from table order by id_column DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Probably it should be `select top 1 * from table order by id_column` or (`order by 1` if id column is first)

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number as below:

```
Select * from (
  SELECT t5.*, co.OrderName, co.OrderDate,
     RowN = Row_number() over(partition by OrderSet order by OrderDate Desc) --Here If OrderSet is not product provide product column here
  FROM #TempTable5 t5
  JOIN #CustomerOrders co 
  ON t5.CustomerGUID = co.CustomerGUID 
  WHERE co.OrderSet = 'Product25'
) a Where a.RowN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT t5.*, co.OrderName, co.OrderDate
    FROM #TempTable5 t5 JOIN #CustomerOrders co ON t5.CustomerGUID = co.CustomerGUID 
WHERE co.OrderSet = 'Product25' AND co.OrderDate = (SELECT TOP(1) OrderDate FROM #CustomerOrders WHERE CustomerGUID = t5.CustomerGUID ORDER BY OrderDate DESC)
```